# CTRL-V not captured in WndProc for WM_PASTE

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to capture paste operations in an inherited TextEdit, but CTRL-V does not gets captured.

I have this

```
 private const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;

 protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
 {
     if (message.Msg == WM_PASTE)
     {
         // my code
     }

     base.WndProc(ref message);
 }
```

If I do right mouse / paste than I make it into `my code`
if I do SHIFT-INSERT than I make it into `my code`
but if I do CTRL-V than I `don't` make it into `my code`

I found the same question with an accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925544/capturing-the-ctrlv-in-vb-net-combobox) but it is in VB and when I try it it does not works. I don't know VB but like I understand this answer the code would be executed with just CTRL or just V, which is not what I want.

My modified code from that answer is

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control) && (keyData == Keys.V)) 
    {
        // my code
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

But I never make it to `my code` with this code

Is there another message then WM_PASTE (302) that I need to listen for ?
Or what is the proper way to capture ALL paste events in my inherited textbox ?

Comment: What do you mean by "inherited textbox"?

Comment: Does this help?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.control?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: @NineBerry It means that I have subclassed an TextEdit from the TextEdit class

Comment: @NickAbbot Yes, I got it working like that in the keydown event, thank you. If you post this as answer I will accept it

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue with a user control inherited from TextBox. The message is received when pressing Ctrl + V in the control. Please provide source code how you have created that inherited control. See [mcve]

Comment: @NineBerry you don't understand the problem, the message being received is not the problem is not my question. The question is how I can capture the receiving, which is now answered by the comment of nick

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I have added the first part of your source code above into a control class inherited from TextBox in Windows Forms. I set a breakpoint at "//my code". The breakpoint is hit when I press Ctrl + V in the textbox.

Comment: @NineBerry and on what line exact did you put the breakpoint

Comment: Right-click the "textedit" control and click Paste to see that intercepting the keystroke is not the solution.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't understand exact what you mean, but I have a working fix now thanks to nickabbot

Comment: @NineBerry I have tried hundreds of times, in my VS the breakpoint is never hit, nor in the VS from my colleague with the same code. I don't understand, I also find many questions in google with the same problem so I am not alone with this I though

Comment: So then provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue. My guess is that there is something else in your project that interferes. For example, a custom context menu or a global command or some other code that already register to handle the shortcut Ctrl +V but don't use the standard TextControl.Paste() to handle it.

Comment: @NineBerry I found what is causing the error, in some textedit's it worked with CTRL-V and in some it did not. After investigating I found out that where it does not works, there is an editmask set to a regex. The TextEdit's in question are derived from devexpress textedit so I don't know if its a problem in their end or at the original textedit, I understand they also derived from the original one. I am now presented with the task of finding a solution for this, I am always open for suggestions

Comment: The issue is know at DevExpress and they claim to have fixed it in 2018, but it is not fixed or it is back, so I hope their support will help me with this

Answer (score 0):

I found out where the problem is.
The TextEdit is a DevExpress TextEdit and it seems that if you put a maskedit of type RegEx then it does not accepts Ctrl-V anymore.

In their forum I can see that this problem was already knonw in 2018 and supposedly fixed, but it seems to be back.

I am now waiting for their support to help me with this.

Comment: This will also trigger when Ctrl + Alt + V is pressed (or AltGr + V on European keyboards). That will not trigger clipboard paste. So you should also check that the ALT key is not down before you handle the event.  `(e.KeyCode == Keys.V) && e.Control && !e.Alt`